# iOS Cordova project: Adding urbanairship-cordova causes error 65 on build

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, urbanairship.com

- Cordova 9.0
- Cordova-ios 5.0.1
- urbanairship-cordova 8.0.0
- Xcode 10.3 (10G8)
- CocoaPods 1.7.5
- macOS 10.14.5

**As soon as I add urbanairship-cordova to my cordova project I can no longer build the project.**

While adding I get the warning Installing "urbanairship-cordova" for ios urbanairship-cordova depends on UrbanAirship-iOS-SDK, which may conflict with another plugin. UrbanAirship-iOS-SDK@11.1.0 is already installed and was not overwritten.

When I build the project with either cordova build ios --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0" --release --buildConfig ../build.json or cordova build ios --release --buildConfig ../build.json

I get this error

The following build commands failed:

```
CompileC /Users/MyName/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/AppName-ggadyhbufqruwffmcouvwgawpjgi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/AppName.build/Release-iphonesimulator/AppName.build/Objects-normal/i386/UAMessageViewController.o AppName/Plugins/urbanairship-cordova/UAMessageViewController.m normal i386 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
```

(1 failure)
xcodebuild: Command failed with exit code 65

Uninstall + Reinstalling CocoaPods didn't help.

When I remove the ios plattform and add it again (as suggested in some postings) I get the error

Installing "urbanairship-cordova" for ios Running command: pod install --verbose Failed to install 'urbanairship-cordova': Error: pod: Command failed with exit code 1 at ChildProcess.whenDone (/Users/.../appname-/source/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:135:23) at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13) at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:961:16) at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:5) pod: Command failed with exit code 1

pod repo update didn't help either

**As soon as I remove urbanairship-cordova everything works fine.**

I want to be able to use urbanairship-cordova in my iOS Cordova app.

I'm really desperate :-(

Answer (score 0):

using urbanairship-cordova 7.6 solved the problem

```
cordova plugin remove urbanairship-cordova
cordova plugin add urbanairship-cordova@7.6.0
```